# Sending parameters from JQuery to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using following JS to get JSON array from a PHP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function() {
               var dataTable =  $('#employee-grid').DataTable( {
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,

                ajax: "employee-grid-data.php", // json datasource

                language: {
        processing:     "Procesando datos...",
        search:         "Buscar:",
        lengthMenu:    "Mostrar _MENU_ doctores/as",
        info:           "Mostrando del doctor/a _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ doctores/as seleccionados" ,
        infoEmpty:      "Mostrando doctor/a 0 al 0 de un total de 0 doctores/as",
        infoFiltered:   "(filtrados de _MAX_ doctores/as)",
        infoPostFix:    "",
        loadingRecords: "Procesando datos...",
        zeroRecords:    "No hay doctores/as que cumplan los criterios",
        emptyTable:     "Noy hay datos que cumplan los criterios",
        paginate: {
            first:      "Primero",
            previous:   "Anterior",
            next:       "Siguiente",
            last:       "Ultimo"
        },
        aria: {
            sortAscending:  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
            sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
        }
    }

                } );

               var colvis = new $.fn.dataTable.ColVis( dataTable, {
                    buttonText: '<img src="images/down.gif" >',
                    activate: 'mouseover',
                    exclude: [ 0 ]  
                   } );
               $( colvis.button() ).prependTo('th:nth-child(1)');

            } );
        </script>
```

It is working fine. Now I need to send  parameters to the PHP file, I have tried adding this to the script,just below the ajax:url line:

```
type: "get", //send it through get method
data:{ajaxid:"1"},
```

and then including this in the PHP to catch the params:

```
$var = $_GET['ajaxid'];
```

but I get 'null' for $var.
I have also tried using POST method instead of GET method, but same result.

Comment: When you var_dump($_GET), what is the output ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix, let me try

Comment: @VasilShaddix, I also get null

Comment: What about `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`. What is the output when you decode it. Can you show your full js code for sending the request ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix, the full js code is already in the question

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you also need to set `datatype: 'json'` in the Ajax parameters.

Comment: `dataType: 'json', data: JSON.stringify(...),`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ajax: "employee-grid-data.php?ajaxid=1"
```

and check Your `$_GET['ajaxid']`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for your problem

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
var ajaxid = 1;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "employee-grid-data.php",
    data:{ ajaxid : ajaxid  }, 
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert(data) 
     }
    })
 </script>
```

and your php file

```
<?php
```

echo $var = $_POST['ajaxid'];

```
?>
```

then you can see your ajaxid value , you can add ajaxid dynamic as your code